# C# Excel Interop Count and Replace

Tags: c#, excel

I have some code to replace text in an excel project(posted below), this code works like a charm. But I also want the number of text instances replaced.
Is there any way to get that?

```
static void ReplaceTextInExcelFile(string filename, string replace, string replacement)
{
object m = Type.Missing;

// open excel.
Application app = new ApplicationClass();

// open the workbook. 
Workbook wb = app.Workbooks.Open(
    filename,
    m, false, m, m, m, m, m, m, m, m, m, m, m, m);

// get the active worksheet. (Replace this if you need to.) 
Worksheet ws = (Worksheet)wb.ActiveSheet;

// get the used range. 
Range r = (Range)ws.UsedRange;

// call the replace method to replace instances. 
bool success = (bool)r.Replace(
    replace,
    replacement,
    XlLookAt.xlWhole,
    XlSearchOrder.xlByRows,
    true, m, m, m);

// save and close. 
wb.Save();
app.Quit();
app = null;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You cant do it directly, but you can run `Find` and `FindNext` function and then replace whatever was found in the search.This will open a scope for taking the count of replacements.

```
Range r = (Range)ws.UsedRange;
int count=0;

Range first=r.Find(replace,m,m,XlLookAt.xlWhole,XlSearchOrder.xlByRows,m,m,m,m);
if(first!=null)
{count++;
Range start=first;
do
{
  start.Value=replacement;
  count++;
  start=r.FindNext(m);
}
while(start!=first);

//do whatever with count
```

Comment: tried this code..it always returns count 2. The start.replace function replaces all instances if the text in one go.

Comment: Otherway is to `start.value=replacement;` and remove `start.Replace`

Comment: thanks for your help. I completed it by looping through each cell in excel and performing matches. Used regex to get me matches. I had a whole list of words to compare against each cell. This approach enabled me to both replace and get count.